# Unable to run selenium in Jenkins

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, selenium, jenkins

I add some C# selenium scripts to my web project (In Visual Studio) and set the priority at the end of the progress run selenium. Everything works fine locally and the browser will automatically pop up and tests. But when I push my project to Git and using Jenkins to run my project. There is no browser pop up when Jenkins running the selenium scripts. But the Jenkins running without any exception. Anyone know how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: I guess, you are using Jenkins as service.

Comment: Yes. I check the "service" from windows. The Jenkins runs as a service. But how it influence?